# How to access child route by its name, but not "parent_route/child_route"?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-router

I have route `zfcadmin/news`. I added route `categories` as child route to `zfcadmin/news`. Now I can get this route by `zfcadmin/news/categories` in views:

```
$this->url('zfcadmin/news/categories', array('action'=>'add'));
```

Is it possible to get route by its own name? i.e `categories` in my case:

```
$this->url('categories', array('action'=>'add'));
```

I need this, because 2nd variant is more relative. Using `url` like in 1st snippet will cause dependency of module, with view with such `url` usage, to module, where `zfcadmin/news` route defined.

Is it possible to get route by its name, but not `parent_parent/parent/child`, where `child` is name of route, I want to get?

Comment: asking this again are we lol

Comment: Old queistion is deleted. This question is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the child route by its "relative" name ("categories"), because ZF2 doesn't support that. You always have to provide its "absolute" name ("zfcadmin/news/categories").

If you don't need the dependency, than you should create a controller in your own module and add a route for that controller in your own module's `module.config.php` file.